# Sinon -- spy a function from different file which is called inside another function

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, sinon

I'm trying to call a function(funA) which is defined in another file and this function internally calls another function(funB) in same file.
Now, when I try to get a call count for funA, I get correct result. However, the same is not true for funB, the call count always returns 0.
Here is my code: 

fileB

```
function funB() {

}

function funA() {
 funB();
}

module.exports = {funA, funB}
```

fileA

```
import * as fileB from "/path/to/fileB";

sinon.spy(fileB);
fileB.funA();
fileB.funA.callCount // returns 1;
fileB.funB.callCount // returns 0; // expected 1
sinon.restore();
```

What am I doing wrong here.
Is it something worng with the import, coz I tried importing using the require keyword and that also doesn't seem to work.
I need to verify that funB is called with appropriate parameters every time funA is called.
How can I achieve that.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the problem here is due to the fact that `sinon.spy` is setting up spies on the functions *only in fileA*. This is because of the way the modules are loaded.

Think about the order in which your files are being loaded:

1. load `fileA`
2. import stuff from `fileB` - this requires `node` to load `fileB` and set everything up
3. set up the spy on functions from `fileB`

The key step here is #2. When `fileB` is loaded and all the symbols are resolved, the spies have not been set up yet. So that reference to `funB` in the middle of `funA` is just a reference to the plain old `funB`, not the "spied" version. And although you're calling the "spied" version of `funA`, it contains a reference to the original value of `funB` and that's what it calls.

In short, sinon does not (and cannot) go back and rewrite references that have already been created, so that reference to `funB` is not affected by the call to `sinon.spy`.

Since both functions are in the same file, there's no way you're going to be able to spy on `funB`. One solution would be to restructure your project so they're in different files - this would allow you to set up spies before initializing. Another solution would be to set up your file so you can inject a spy/stub version of `funB` before running your tests.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, `funA` always calls the original `funB`.

There is alternative: change the implementation of fileB using object.

Example:

```js
// File: fileB
// Create object fileB.
const fileB = {
  funB() {},

  funA() {
    // Note: funA calls method funB inside object fileB.
    fileB.funB();
  },
}

module.exports = fileB;
```

```js
// File: fileA
import sinon from 'sinon';
import fileB from './fileB';
// This spy will replace all method in the object with wrapped original method.
sinon.spy(fileB);
// You call spied funA, which will call spied funB.
fileB.funA();

console.log(fileB.funA.callCount); // returns 1;
console.log(fileB.funB.callCount); // returns 0; // expected 1

sinon.restore();
```

Result:

```
$ npx mocha fileA.js
1
1


  0 passing (0ms)

$
```